# Is there a way to integrate java servlet faces in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

I' writing a web app with spring boot and i want use the [primefaces components](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/getstarted.xhtml) in my views.
Is there a way to integrate java servlet faces in spring boot?

Comment: Tried doing a simple search in a search engine? And please read [ask]

Comment: Oh and it is 'JavaServer Faces' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The valid answer to this question is: *"Yes there is"*